# Display commits to private repos on the GitHub contributions graph

Tags: github

How can I display the commits I've made on private repos on my "Your Contributions" graph?

I have a lot of commits but I am only showing 40 contributions on my graph and so I would like to show more contributions since I believe those 40 are only for my public commits. Thanks!

Comment: Can you see these contributions when you're logged in to GitHub? I don't think that contributions to private repositories will show up if you're not logged in, and I'm not aware of any way to change that. But you [should be able to see them when you're logged in](http://i.imgur.com/sDLXwRs.png), assuming you still have access to the repositories.

Comment: it turned out that if I do not push the changes to the master branch(or merge master with the branch i've been commiting to) then no commits will actually show on my console.

Comment: Better for either [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) (since it's not dealing with coding but how the interface/accounts work) or direct to GitHub:Support

Answer (score 6):

You can do it as described here: [Publicizing or hiding your private contributions on your profile](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/publicizing-or-hiding-your-private-contributions-on-your-profile)

Just open your profile, go to the Contribution settings above your contributions graph and select Private contributions:

[image]

Comment: Hi Twinsinc. A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful 
without it: [add context around the link] 
(https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) 
so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there, then 
quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target 
page is unavailable. 
[Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted] 
(https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Kind Regards.